# Problema con autenticacion con token en API REST

Tags: fetch, jwt

```
Hola estoy haciendo un curso de WEBAPI en .NETcore, estamos viendo la parte de autenticacion e hicimos una pequeña API con la BD Northwind.
```

Con un metodo de login que valida usuario y contraseña se genera un token para poder consumir los metodos que luego devolveran los datos.
Escribi un cliente bien sencillo en JavaScript puro y logro que la api me devuelva el token pero a la hora de autenticar el metodo que trae los datos, la misma falla (error 401).
El codigo del FE es el siguiente:

```
async function GetToken(usuario){
    let resp= await fetch(url+'Login',{
        method:'post',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        },
        body:JSON.stringify(usuario)
    });
    let token=await resp.text();
    return  token;
}
```

esta funcion me devuelve el codigo de manera ok [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero la funcion que debe traer los datos no autentica:

```
     async function GetProductos(_token){
    console.log(_token);
    let resp=await fetch(url+'Price',{
        headers:{
            'Authorization':'Bearer'+_token,
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        }
    });
    let producto=await resp.json();
    return producto;
}
```

Hay algun error en el codigo?

Answer (score 0):

En la función getproducts, la propiedad headers tiene que ser:

```
headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}`introducir el código aquí`
```

Vamos, que despues de Bearer tienes que poner un espacio.

Comment: Muchas gracias, era ese el problema, ya funciona correctamente.